# How to view created jms queue in activemq after integrating jboss 6?

Tags: java, jboss, activemq-classic

I have configured activemq in jboss using this [link](http://activemq.apache.org/integrating-apache-activemq-with-jboss.html). If i run standalone activemq server i can able create/delete/update queue in the browser using this `http://localhost:8161/admin/queues.jsp`

Now activemq was configured in jboss.If browse above url not found message displayed.

How to manipulate queue configuration in integrated activemq?

Comment: What version of ActiveMQ are you using? This tutorial is quite outdated. On the other side you can manipulate with queues through JMX. Try jconsole.

Answer (score 0):

The web gui is a simple web application that is deployed on the bundled Jetty server that came with the standalone version of ActiveMQ.

You can deploy that, or preferably hawt.io to your JBoss instead. hawt.io can even remote connect to your ActiveMQ using JMX. Try it out!